# WPF: data won't display in my datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm learning XAML with WPF and i'm trying to display some data in a grid, but i can't for the life of me get it to show. the fields appear, but they're empty without text. here's the XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="MoodWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MoodWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="810.573" 
    Width="1026.432"
    MinWidth="600">
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="#333333">
    <DataGrid Width="400" Height="400" x:Name="trackList" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF404040" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ColumnHeaderHeight="22" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" RowBackground="#FF404040" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF333333" RowHeight="20" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Track" Header="Track" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Artist" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Album" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Time" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

and the C# with which im trying to insert some random data

```
namespace MoodWPF
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        // create and add three lines of fake data to be displayed, here

        trackList.Items.Add(new DataItem { Track = "a.1", Artist = "a.2", Album = "a.3", Time = "a.4" });
        trackList.Items.Add(new DataItem { Track = "a.1", Artist = "a.2", Album = "a.3", Time = "a.4" });
        trackList.Items.Add(new DataItem { Track = "a.1", Artist = "a.2", Album = "a.3", Time = "a.4" });

        /*
        Collection<DataItem> users = new Collection<DataItem>();
        users.Add(new DataItem { Track = "firstname-1", Artist = "lastname-1" });
        users.Add(new DataItem { Track = "firstname-2", Artist = "lastname-2" });
        users.Add(new DataItem { Track = "firstname-3", Artist = "lastname-3" });
        users.Add(new DataItem { Track = "firstname-4", Artist = "lastname-4" });
        trackList.ItemsSource = users;

    }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public string Track { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

}

what am i doing wrong/not doing? keep in mind i'm a beginner with WPF and Xaml

Comment: if you using `DataGrid.Columns` - then you should also add `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`. Or remove all <DataGrid.Columns> from your XAML - then DataGrid will automatically detect your columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need only text try:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Track" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Track}" Header="Track"/>
   ...
```

or you need specific template:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Artist" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues,

(i) You need to have a collection to bind to DataGrid, hence add the items to a List or ObservableCollection

**Code Behind:**

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                List<DataItem> data = new List<DataItem>();
                data.Add(new DataItem { Track = "a.1", Artist = "a.2", Album = "a.3", Time = "a.4" });
                data.Add(new DataItem { Track = "a.1", Artist = "a.2", Album = "a.3", Time = "a.4" });
                data.Add(new DataItem { Track = "a.1", Artist = "a.2", Album = "a.3", Time = "a.4" });
                trackList.ItemsSource = data;
            }

        }
        public class DataItem
        {
            public string Track { get; set; }
            public string Artist { get; set; }
            public string Album { get; set; }
            public string Time { get; set; }
        }
```

(ii)Set DataGrid  `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

If you set AutoGenerateColums= false,

**XAML:**

```
  <DataGrid Width="400" Height="400" x:Name="trackList" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FF404040" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ColumnHeaderHeight="22" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" RowBackground="#FF404040" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF333333" RowHeight="20" SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Track}"   x:Name="Track" Header="Track" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Artist}"   Header="Artist" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Album}"   Header="Album" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Time}"  Header="Time" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to bind your model (probably a List of specific object) to the DataGrid, and its attributes to its repective columns.

Kind of:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TrackList" DataContext="{Binding Source=TrackList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Track" Binding="{Binding Track}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist" Binding="{Binding Artist}"/>
            ...........
            ...........
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```